# How to write this Program in methods

Tags: java, methods

This the program I have written to check for an Armstrong No. how do I write it with methods

For example if I want to break it down into following 4 methods

- void getnum()
- int check()
- void dispsum
- and a main method to enable the task

  ```
  import java.util.Scanner;
  class Arm_check1
  {
      public static void main(String args[])
      {
          int n=0;
          int ori;
          int z;
          System.out.println("Enter a No.");
          Scanner Prakhar=new Scanner(System.in);
          n=Prakhar.nextInt();
          int digits=(int)Math.floor(Math.log10(n)+1);
          System.out.println("No of Digits :"+digits);
          int a[]=new int[digits];
          int sum=0;
          ori=n;
          for(int i=0;i<digits;i++)
          {
              a[i]=n%10;
              n=n/10;
          }
          for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
          {
              sum=(int)Math.pow(a[i],3)+sum;
          }
          System.out.println(sum);
          System.out.println(ori);
          if(sum == ori)
          {
              System.out.println("No. is Armstrong");
          }
          else
              System.out.println("No. is not Armstrong");
      }
  }
  ```

This is the only way I see of doing it but my Professor says that we are not allowed to use the same in our exams, i.e ...

```
void main(){
getnum()
} .... and So On..
```

This is what I wrote again after Yluns answer

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    class Arm_check2
    {
        int n=0;
        int ori;
        int sum;
        void getnum()
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a No.");
            Scanner Prakhar=new Scanner(System.in);
            n=Prakhar.nextInt();
            check();
        }

        int check()
        {
            int digits=(int)Math.floor(Math.log10(n)+1);
            System.out.println("No of Digits :"+digits);
            int a[]=new int[digits];
            int sum=0;
            ori=n;
            for(int i=0;i<digits;i++)
            {
                a[i]=n%10;
                n=n/10;
            }
            for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
            {
                sum=(int)Math.pow(a[i],3)+sum;
            }
            dispsum(sum);
            return sum;

        }

        void dispsum(int sum)
        {
            System.out.println(sum);
            System.out.println(ori);
            if(sum == ori)
            {
                System.out.println("No. is Armstrong");
            }
            else
                System.out.println("No. is not Armstrong");
        }
        void main()
        {
            getnum();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not first try it yourself. Otherwise by posting it here without showing your efforts, you're only cheating yourself out of a valuable learning opportunity.

Comment: This looks like a homework question.

Comment: It is easy dear.Just break the code

Comment: I understand the concept of using methods just do not know how to get on with it any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Since I have not seen a reasonable attempt, I will not write any example code for you. However I will give you these references to read.

Read up about `methods`: [Java Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html). They are declared following the format:

```
(private/public) static (return type) (name of method) (parameters){
    //method body
}
```

Your main method should handle calling your other methods.

Comment: For the record this isn't homework, rather a practice question I scavenged off somewhere

Answer (score 1):

Your main method has to stay in this way:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  // function body
}
```

I see youve splitted your old function body into new functions, why dont you try to call all of those new functions in the order you need?

And you declared on of them as `int` return-type therefore you have to store that result to get the last part of your code working.